# List all values in an array without repeats

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, unique

Suppose I have a 100 x 100 matrix composed of some combination of 250s, 125s, 15s and 9s. I would like to return a sorted vector of all of the unique values in this matrix.

Something in the matter of:

```
sort(somefunction(matrix))=vector
```

The result I would like to get is thus:

```
vector=9,15,125,250
```

Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
b = unique(a)
```

Check the docs on [`unique`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html)

```
A = randi(9,10,10);
unique(A)
ans =
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
```

Answer (score -3):

```
b = sort(a(:));
```

This should do the work sort your matrix;

And this shall return all values into a vector.

```
b = unique(a(:));
```

Comment: @Adriaan, true unique should do that work, and if he wants to sort as well then fist code line would do the job.

Comment: Using `sort` then calling `unique` after is superfluous.  The default output of `unique` already sorts all of the unique values in a matrix or array.

Comment: One command if he wants to sort, and other command if he wants all elements in the matrix appearing once sorted.
I read his question and thought first he only wanted to sort...